# NULL handling in a least() function in Postgres/SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I want the query to return the least of the two columns. However if both col1 and col2 are NULL, then return NULL. I've tried coalesce() and nvl() but both don't handle the case when both col1 and col2 are NULL.

For col1 = 3 and col = 2:

```
select least(coalesce(3, 1000000), coalesce(2, 1000000))
```

This works, output is 2.

This also works for col1 = 3 and col2 = NULL:

```
select least(coalesce(3, 1000000), coalesce(NULL, 1000000))
```

However, this does not work when col1 = NULL and col2 = NULL

```
select least(coalesce(null, 1000000), coalesce(null, 1000000))
```

This gives me 1000000 instead of null. 
How can I account for this scenario?

Comment: I don't really understand the question least does return null if both arguments are null.  It seems like you are comparing more than just two columns here.  Can you provide a sample table, sample data, and an expected outcome?

Comment: I agree with Jeremy your question is confusing, because: `least(null, null)` **will** return `null`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.*, x.least_val
from (values (2, 3)) t(col1, col2) cross join lateral
     (select min(col) as least_val
      from (values (t.col1), (t.col2)) v(col)
     ) x;
```

You seem to want the semantics of `min()`, so this does exactly the `min()`.

If you really want to use `least()` and a "magic" value, you can use `nullif()`:

```
select nullif(least(coalesce(3, 1000000), coalesce(NULL, 1000000)), 1000000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear. I believe that you are trying to compare two columns of a table. Null has no value. So when you use it in least(), **the non-null value is always returned unless all the values compared are null**. So you can replace 0 for null as follows.

```
select least(coalesce(0, value_1), coalesce(0, value_2));
```

Comment: Hana, select least(coalesce(null, 1000000), coalesce(null, 1000000)) will not return null, because coalesce selects the first non-null value. coalesce(null, 1000000) -> 1000000. and least(1000000, 1000000) -> 1000000

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of case statement comparing two columns as well.

```
  CREATE TABLE emp_data (
Value1 int , 
value2 int
);

insert into emp_data (value1, value2) values (100, 200), (200,200), (300,150) 

Select case when value1 > value2 then value2
when value1 < value2 then value1  else null end as Comparison, value1, value2
from emp_data
```

Output:

```
Comparison Value1 value2 
     100         100    200
                 200    200
     150         300    150
```

Here is the fiddle :

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fbd19a9bbc6563d700495fa487888606

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the result should be null however. This example doesn't account for that i believe

Comment: @Hana it does give nulls, I have updated fiddle and the case statement with some sample data.